# Some faces don't show the assigned material

Tags: mesh, materials, properties

I did a random selection and assigned a new yellow material to them. The image below shows all the selected faces on which I assigned the material. However, as you can see, only few of them have the color applied. I tried to select those faces individually and assign the material on them. They still don't show the color. Weird thing is that when I click on those faces, it does show on the material properties that they have the yellow material assigned. Why is it happening?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have duplicate geometry and overlapping faces

Comment: Thank you! You seem to be right, but I wonder why it happened. I just subdivided a cube, extruded individual faces and did inset faces.